# Get operatorID from external SMSC

Tags: smpp, kannel

My kannel works great in smpp, deliver SMS postback me DLR for updating status.

When I send a SMS to my customer, i would like to know on which operator (Orange, Bouygues, ...) i sent the SMS.

I work with a SMSC called Highconnexion (in France) and according to its technical support, Highconnexion send me the op_id into an optional field in DELIVER_SM. The field is referenced by the value 0x1402.

He tells me that he think that kannel can get this information but don't know how because he is not a kannel specialist.

I try to find how to get this op_id, but impossible to find a response on google search.

Is someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You now know TLV code (0x1402). What you also need is TLV length and type — these you have to ask from the SMSC owner.

After that please refer to kannel docs here: http://www.kannel.org/download/1.5.0/userguide-1.5.0/userguide.html#META-DATA

And this conversation here:
http://www.kannel.org/pipermail/users/2010-October/013995.html

Comment: In fact, I was on kannel 1.4.3 so every things i read about TLV don't work for me. I know why now :-)